# Abstract auto function in D

Tags: d

Is there any way to have an `abstract auto` function in D?

If I declare a class as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
    abstract auto foo();
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
main.d(12): Error: function declaration without return type. (Note that constructors are always named 'this')
main.d(12): Error: no identifier for declarator foo()
```

I'm wondering why this isn't possible? And are there any alternatives to obtain similar functionality?

Comment: What would you expect this to do? If you put `auto` on the return type of a function that means it should try to infer the type from the return expression in the function body. It can hardly do that at the same time you're telling it there isn't a function body? Please spell out what you actually want to do here.

Comment: See my comment below. I've sorted it out, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because `auto` is a placeholder for a *static* type. The *abstract* class can't know what the type should be as it's not specified. Even if this did work, `foo()` may return different types based on its implementations in derived classes. You probably don't want that, since it would mean the API could vary depending on the implementation.

If you absolutely need this kind of functionality, look at [std.variant](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html).

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks. I was clumsily trying to use the auto keyword as a replacement for generics in a class where the return type of the function is given as a template parameter. I now see why this doesn't make sense.